# Will upgrading Sonarqube from 3.3.2 to 4.5.1 cause DB table changes

Tags: sonarqube

I am looking to upgrade Sonarqube from 3.3.2 to 4.5.1. However, will this cause a change in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I don't know how to do a better answer, except to point you at the successive [release notes for Sonar/SonarQube](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) or the [source code for the actual migrations](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/db/migrate) if you want to peek at what is done under the hood.

Note that a direct upgrade path from 3.3.2 to 4.5.1 is fully supported, so you won't have to manually apply intermediate upgrades.

Comment: Will this cause use to remodel our data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, sorry. Which data are you talking about? Are you querying the SonarQube database directly?